# How to construct ground surface of infinite size in a 3D CAD application?

Tags: graphics, 3d, geometry, cad

I am trying to create an application similar in UI to Sketchup. As a first step, I need to display the ground surface stretching out in all directions. What is the best way to do this?

Options:

1. Create a sufficiently large regular polygon stretching out in all directions from the origin. Here there is a possibility of the user hitting the edges and falling off the surface of the earth.
2. Model the surface of the earth as a sphere/spheroid. Here I will be limiting my vertex co-ordinates to very large values prone to rounding off errors. (Radius of earth is 6371000000 millimeter).
3. Same as 1 but dynamically extend the ends of the earth as the user gets close to them.

**What is the usual practice**?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you would do neither of these, but instead use a virtual ground.

So you just find out, what portion of the ground is visible in the viewport and then create a plane large enough to fill that. With some reasonable maxiumum, which simulates the end of the line of sight aka horizon as we know it.

Comment: This is similar to option 1 unless I am mistaken. Can you give me a bit more detail on locating "end of the line of sight"?

Comment: Its more a mixture of 3 and 1 without really creating an object. What I mean with locating the end of sight is, that if you don't have a static ground, but just define ground as the intersection of a) a plane at some coordiantes and b) the cone of the viewport (angle of vision and direction of view), you will get either get a limited intersection of both when viewing at the ground from high above, or you will have a horizon line which has to be defined as a limit on visibility.

Comment: Rendering the ground as a large sphere will just naturally give you 2 things: A plane (well almost) and a limit of vision. But you don't need to get things that complicated when you can simulate that limit in vision just by not rendering things that are outside of that range.